# algebraic error when running "aggregate" function on dataset

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I'm learning hadoop/pig/hive through running through tutorials on hortonworks.com

I have indeed tried to find a link to the tutorial, but unfortunately it only ships with the ISA image that they provide to you. It's not actually hosted on their website.

```
batting = load 'Batting.csv' using PigStorage(',');
runs = FOREACH batting GENERATE $0 as playerID, $1 as year, $8 as runs;
grp_data = GROUP runs by (year);
max_runs = FOREACH grp_data GENERATE group as grp,MAX(runs.runs) as max_runs;
join_max_run = JOIN max_runs by ($0, max_runs), runs by (year,runs);
join_data = FOREACH join_max_run GENERATE $0 as year, $2 as playerID, $1 as runs;
dump join_data;
```

I've copied their code **exactly** as it was stated in the tutorial and I'm getting this output:

```
2013-06-14 14:34:37,969 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1.1.3.0.0-107 (rexported) compiled May 20 2013, 03:04:35
2013-06-14 14:34:37,977 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hue/jobcache/job_201306140401_0020/attempt_201306140401_0020_m_000000_0/work/pig_1371245677965.log
2013-06-14 14:34:38,412 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /usr/lib/hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2013-06-14 14:34:38,598 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://sandbox:8020
2013-06-14 14:34:38,998 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: sandbox:50300
2013-06-14 14:34:40,819 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_DOUBLE 1 time(s).
2013-06-14 14:34:40,827 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: HASH_JOIN,GROUP_BY
2013-06-14 14:34:41,115 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2013-06-14 14:34:41,160 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.CombinerOptimizer - Choosing to move algebraic foreach to combiner
2013-06-14 14:34:41,201 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler$LastInputStreamingOptimizer - Rewrite: POPackage->POForEach to POJoinPackage
2013-06-14 14:34:41,213 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 3
2013-06-14 14:34:41,213 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - Merged 1 map-reduce splittees.
2013-06-14 14:34:41,214 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - Merged 1 out of total 3 MR operators.
2013-06-14 14:34:41,214 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 2
2013-06-14 14:34:41,488 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2013-06-14 14:34:41,551 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2013-06-14 14:34:41,555 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Using reducer estimator: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
2013-06-14 14:34:41,559 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=6398990
2013-06-14 14:34:41,559 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting Parallelism to 1
2013-06-14 14:34:44,244 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job5371236206169131677.jar
2013-06-14 14:34:49,495 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - jar file Job5371236206169131677.jar created
2013-06-14 14:34:49,517 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up multi store job
2013-06-14 14:34:49,529 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2013-06-14 14:34:49,530 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2013-06-14 14:34:49,530 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2013-06-14 14:34:49,755 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2013-06-14 14:34:50,144 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2013-06-14 14:34:50,145 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2013-06-14 14:34:50,256 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2013-06-14 14:34:50,316 [JobControl] INFO  com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader - Loaded native gpl library
2013-06-14 14:34:50,444 [JobControl] INFO  com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec - Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev cf4e7cbf8ed0f0622504d008101c2729dc0c9ff3]
2013-06-14 14:34:50,665 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy - Snappy native library is available
2013-06-14 14:34:50,666 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Loaded the native-hadoop library
2013-06-14 14:34:50,666 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy - Snappy native library loaded
2013-06-14 14:34:50,680 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 1
2013-06-14 14:34:52,796 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_201306140401_0021
2013-06-14 14:34:52,796 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases batting,grp_data,max_runs,runs
2013-06-14 14:34:52,796 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: batting[1,10],runs[2,7],max_runs[4,11],grp_data[3,11] C: max_runs[4,11],grp_data[3,11] R: max_runs[4,11]
2013-06-14 14:34:52,796 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - More information at: http://sandbox:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201306140401_0021
2013-06-14 14:36:01,993 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 50% complete
2013-06-14 14:36:04,767 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2013-06-14 14:36:04,768 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201306140401_0021 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2013-06-14 14:36:04,768 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2013-06-14 14:36:05,029 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2106: Error executing an algebraic function
2013-06-14 14:36:05,030 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2013-06-14 14:36:05,042 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107   0.11.1.1.3.0.0-107  mapred  2013-06-14 14:34:41 2013-06-14 14:36:05 HASH_JOIN,GROUP_BY

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201306140401_0021   batting,grp_data,max_runs,runs  MULTI_QUERY,COMBINER    Message: Job failed! Error - # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201306140401_0021_m_000000  

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://sandbox:8020/user/hue/batting.csv"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201306140401_0021   ->  null,
null


2013-06-14 14:36:05,042 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2013-06-14 14:36:05,043 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias join_data
Details at logfile: /hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hue/jobcache/job_201306140401_0020/attempt_201306140401_0020_m_000000_0/work/pig_1371245677965.log
```

When switching this part: `MAX(runs.runs)`  to `avg(runs.runs)` then I am getting a completely different issue:

```
2013-06-14 14:38:25,694 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1.1.3.0.0-107 (rexported) compiled May 20 2013, 03:04:35
2013-06-14 14:38:25,695 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hue/jobcache/job_201306140401_0022/attempt_201306140401_0022_m_000000_0/work/pig_1371245905690.log
2013-06-14 14:38:26,198 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /usr/lib/hadoop/.pigbootup not found
2013-06-14 14:38:26,438 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://sandbox:8020
2013-06-14 14:38:26,824 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: sandbox:50300
2013-06-14 14:38:28,238 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve avg using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hue/jobcache/job_201306140401_0022/attempt_201306140401_0022_m_000000_0/work/pig_1371245905690.log
```

**Anybody know what the issue might be?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure lot of people would have figured this out. I combined Eugene's solution with the original code from Hortonworks such that we get the exact output as specific in the tutorial.
Following code works and produces exact output as specified in the tutorial:

```
batting = LOAD 'Batting.csv' using PigStorage(',');
runs_raw = FOREACH batting GENERATE $0 as playerID, $1 as year, $8 as runs;
runs = FILTER runs_raw BY runs > 0;
grp_data = group runs by (year);
max_runs = FOREACH grp_data GENERATE group as grp, MAX(runs.runs) as max_runs;
join_max_run = JOIN max_runs by ($0, max_runs), runs by (year,runs);
join_data = FOREACH join_max_run GENERATE $0 as year, $2 as playerID, $1 as runs;
```

dump join_data;

Note: line "runs = FILTER runs_raw BY runs > 0;" is additional than what has been provided by Hortonworks, thanks to Eugene for sharing working code which I used to modify original Hortonworks code to make it work.

Comment: got your email also :)

Answer (score 2):

UDFs are case sensitive, so at least to answer the second part of your question - you'll need to use `AVG(runs.runs)` instead of `avg(runs.runs)`

It's likely that once you correct your syntax you'll get the original error you reported...

Comment: no sir! AVG works. MAX does not work. probably a bug in their code!

Answer (score 1):

i am having the same exact same issue with exact same log output, but this solution doesn't work because i believe changing MAX with AVG here dumps the whole purpose of this hortonworks.com tutorial - it was to get the MAX runs by playerID for each year.

**UPDATE**

Finally i got it resolved - you have to either remove the first line in Batting.csv (column names) or edit your Pig Latin code like this:

```
batting = LOAD ‘Batting.csv’ using PigStorage(‘,’);
runs_raw = FOREACH batting GENERATE $0 as playerID, $1 as year, $8 as runs;
runs = FILTER runs_raw BY runs > 0;
grp_data = group runs by (year);
max_runs = FOREACH grp_data GENERATE group as grp, MAX(runs.runs) as max_runs;
dump max_runs;
```

After that you should be able to complete tutorial correctly and get the proper result.

It also looks like this is due to the "bug" in the older versions of Pig rhich was used in the tutorial

Comment: thanks so much!!! how are the rest of the tutorials going for you? have you installed a cluster yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify appropriate data type for playerID, year & runs like below:

runs = FOREACH batting GENERATE $0 as playerID:int, $1 as year:chararray, $8 as runs:int;

Not, it should work.